# Meteor Get request

Tags: meteor, get

Bear with me for any mistakes/wrong terminology since I am new to all this. I am using meteor to develop my project and i need to make a get request to an external API. (I already added `meteor add http`) Below is my code:

```
HTTP.call( 'GET', 'url', {}, function( error, response ) {
  if ( error ) {
    console.log( error );
  } else {
    console.log( response );
  }
});
```

If i use the code inside my Client folder in Meteor I get the following error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access meteor` It has something to do with CORS which I didn't understand how to implement. If I use the code above in my Server side I do get the correct response in the console but how do I use it as a var on my client javascript code?

Comment: Its up to the service provider to enable CORS, but there are ways that you can attempt to hack around it (but its not pretty).  I would suggest you simply perform your call from the server from within a Meteor method and then call the method from your Meteor client code.  Easy, simple, and straightforward.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed it. On client side

```
Meteor.call("getURL",'url',{},function(err,res){
     if(err){
       console.log('Error: '+err);
     }
     if(!err){
     console.log('Response: '+res);
        }
```

and on server

```
Meteor.methods({
  'getURL': function(url_l){
     console.log("Request: "+url_l)
     return HTTP.get(url_l)
   } 
});
```

Comment: Please note that this creates a security hole where anyone can cause your server to make http calls to *any* url as many times as they want.

Answer (score 0):

Tou can use .call function of HTTP and pass your header in options:

```
HTTP.call(method, url, [options], [asyncCallback])
```

***Arguments***

**method** String

```
The HTTP method to use, such as "GET", "POST", or "HEAD".
```

**url** String

```
The URL to retrieve.
```

**asyncCallback** Function

```
Optional callback. If passed, the method runs asynchronously, instead of synchronously, and calls asyncCallback. On the client, this callback is required.
```

***Options***

**content** String

```
String to use as the HTTP request body.
```

**data** Object

```
JSON-able object to stringify and use as the HTTP request body. Overwrites content.
```

**query** String

```
Query string to go in the URL. Overwrites any query string in url.
```

**params** Object

```
Dictionary of request parameters to be encoded and placed in the URL (for GETs) or request body (for POSTs). If content or data is specified, params will always be placed in the URL.
```

**auth** String

```
HTTP basic authentication string of the form "username:password"
```

**headers** Object

```
Dictionary of strings, headers to add to the HTTP request.
```

**timeout** Number

```
Maximum time in milliseconds to wait for the request before failing. There is no timeout by default.
```

**followRedirects** Boolean

```
If true, transparently follow HTTP redirects. Cannot be set to false on the client. Default true.
```

**npmRequestOptions** Object

```
On the server, HTTP.call is implemented by using the npm request module. Any options in this object will be passed directly to the request invocation.
```

**beforeSend** Function

```
On the client, this will be called before the request is sent to allow for more direct manipulation of the underlying XMLHttpRequest object, which will be passed as the first argument. If the callback returns false, the request will be not be send.
```

Souce:  [Here](https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html)